# Reset state = initialState not working for me in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to reset state using below code. But I don't know why it gives me the error 'initialState' is not defined. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState:
    // JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item')) ||
    {
      products: [],
      quantity: 0,
      total: 0,
    },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.products.push(action.payload);
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
      // localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(state));
    },
    deleteItem: (state, action) => {
      state.quantity -= 1;
      state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
    reset: (state) => {
      state = initialState;
    },
  },
});

export const { addProduct, reset, deleteItem } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHypI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually declare the initial state to reset the state .

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState:
    // JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item')) ||
    {
      products: [],
      quantity: 0,
      total: 0,
    },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.products.push(action.payload);
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
      // localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(state));
    },
    deleteItem: (state, action) => {
      state.quantity -= 1;
      state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
    reset: (state) => {
      state = {
      products: [],
      quantity: 0,
      total: 0,
    };
    },
  },
});

export const { addProduct, reset, deleteItem } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Oh, I got it. It works. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me by returning initialState instead of assigning it. Like this:

```
reset: (state) => {
  return initialState; // INSTEAD OF THIS state = initialState;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. You can also keep something from the state if you wish, like so: `return { ...initialState, paramToKeep: state.paramToKeep }`

Answer (score 2):

`state = something` **never** works in RTK reducers. You can modify the object in the variable `state`, you cannot reassign the variable `state` to a new object.

Do `return something` instead of `state = something`. This is described in the [Writing Reducers with `immer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state) documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the initialState at all. You could pull the initialState out of the slice and it should work.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
      products: [],
      quantity: 0,
      total: 0,
    };

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState:
    // JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item')) ||
    initialState
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.products.push(action.payload);
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
      // localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(state));
    },
    deleteItem: (state, action) => {
      state.quantity -= 1;
      state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
    reset: (state) => {
      state = initialState;
    },
  },
});

export const { addProduct, reset, deleteItem } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: but the initial state value is changed when a data is added ,so it can't be reset ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using redux toolkit...this is how you do it....

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getStringArray } from "../helperFunctions";
const initialState = {
  game: {
    MODAL_OPEN: false,
    END: false,
    PLAYING: false,
    LEVEL: 1,
    WON: false,
    LOST: false,
    wordLength: 5,
    RANDOM_WORD: "",
    colIndex: 0,
    rowIndex: 0,
    ATTEMPTS: 6,
    darkMode: false,
    INIT: false,
  },
  ROW_ARRAY: new Array(6).fill(new Array(5).fill({ value: "", color: "" })),
  ROW_ARRAY_NEW: new Array(6).fill(
    new Array(5).fill({ value: "", color: "#ddd" })
  ),
};

const gameSlice = createSlice({
  name: "game",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    resetGame: (state) => (state = initialState),
```